# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: File is not defined" [Vuetify + NuxtJS]

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

(I'm using Vuetify and NuxtJS)

I get this error when I'm trying to implement the component : `v-file-input`

[image: screenshot of error]

file.vue :

```
<template>
    <v-file-input
        counter
        multiple
        show-size
        truncate-length="15"
    ></v-file-input>
</template>
```

I just have this problem in this file, not in other one.

When I copy paste some other code from my project in this file, it works, if I don't modify it.

Any idea why it happens ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `v-file-input` uses browser only APIs.

you can tell nuxt to render this only client side with `client-only`

```html
<client-only>
  <v-file-input
    counter
    multiple
    show-size
    truncate-length="15"
  ></v-file-input>
</client-only>
```

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components/#the-client-only-component